# error while performing LDA dimensional reduction with scikit-learn

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I've got imported the Dataset from this URL in the pandas Dataframe called **df**:
[https://www.kaggle.com/jakeshbohaju/brain-tumor?select=Brain+Tumor.csv](https://www.kaggle.com/jakeshbohaju/brain-tumor?select=Brain%20Tumor.csv)

But, while running a linear discriminant analysis, I always get the error on the bottom.

```
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis
X = df.drop(['label','Image'], axis=1)
y = df[['label']]

lda = LinearDiscriminantAnalysis(n_components=2)
X_r2 = lda.fit(X, y).transform(X)
```

Error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-41-f7a0f19db224> in <module>
     25 lda = LinearDiscriminantAnalysis(n_components=2)
     26 lda2 = LinearDiscriminantAnalysis(n_components=2)
---> 27 X_r3 = lda2.fit(X_train,y_train.values.ravel()).transform(X_train)
     28 X_r2 = lda.fit(X, y).transform(X)
     29 

~/miniforge3/envs/pyM1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/discriminant_analysis.py in fit(self, X, y)
    537         else:
    538             if self.n_components > max_components:
--> 539                 raise ValueError(
    540                     "n_components cannot be larger than min(n_features, "
    541                     "n_classes - 1)."

ValueError: n_components cannot be larger than min(n_features, n_classes - 1).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

`lda.fit(X, y)` does not return anything and hence you cannot call the method called `.transform()` on it. The API will allow you to call a method only if it is already defined. Please see the documentation.

Change it to this. I would also encourage you to spend more time on the documentation.

```py
lda = LinearDiscriminantAnalysis(n_components=2)

# either use: lda.fit_transform(X, y)
X_r2 = lda.fit_transform(X, y)

## PREFERRED WAY
# or, use: lda.fit(X, y)
# followed by lda.transform(X)
lda.fit(X, y)
X_r2 = lda.transform(X)
```

### References

1. [`LinearDiscriminantAnalysis` -  Docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.discriminant_analysis.LinearDiscriminantAnalysis.html)

Comment: With your code I still still this error message: /python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py:63: DataConversionWarning:

A column-vector y was passed when a 1d array was expected. Please change the shape of y to (n_samples, ), for example using ravel().

Comment: using ravel() has no effect, I'm still getting an error

Comment: There is an example here. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.discriminant_analysis.LinearDiscriminantAnalysis.html. Please try running that first. Check the shapes of X, y and transformed-X. Then make sure that your `Xtrain` and `ytrain` are also following the same shapes.

Comment: @scapiest Thank you, for accepting the answer. Please also consider **voting up** the answer, if it helped you.